# Auto Hot Keys with coding text

Tags: c#, autohotkey

I would like to do an auto hot key script that will paste:

```
{ get; set; }
```

for C#

Is this possible or does it not know how to handle the spaces, {, ;?

I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
    ^NumPad3::
    SendInput, { get; set; }
    return
```

Comment: Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V.   { get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }{ get; set; }

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2017

Comment: You need to escape curlies in autohotkey like so: `{{}` for `{` and `{}}` for `}`. Semi colons start comment lines unless you escape them like `\`;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma, semicolon, and other characters such as {}^!+# have special meaning in AHK and need to be escaped in order to be interpreted differently than it normally would.

```
F1:: SendInput, {{} get`; set`; {}}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm#Escape_Sequences

The easiest way to send such a text is

```
F2::
Send {Raw}  
(
{ get; set; }
)
return
```

or

```
F3::
Send {Blind}{Text} ; [v1.1.27+] 
(
{ get; set; }
)
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: Thanks user3419297!   This worked fine: F1:: SendInput, `{{`} get`; set`; `{}`}  (I had to make sure I was doing it in the right section where get; set; are allowed etc.!)